# How to feed input to an interactive bash script from a text file

Tags: bash, io

I have a script (from a vendor.. for masking passwords) that walks through a series of user inputs, and generates some output based on input. I would like to be able to wrap another script around it which feeds the input from a text file, and then captures the output for later use. Anyone have any examples of this?

UPDATE: I've done some digging, and it turns out the shell script is kicking off a java process which is what is requesting user input. xargs and <,>,| don't seem to work for this.

Comment: Not enough content for an answer, but check out [`expect`](http://expect.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Did you try normal I/O redirection? Depending on how the script reads its input, sometimes that will work.

Answer (score 6):

`myscript < input_file > output_file` (from the command line) will read `input_file` line by line as if it were user input, and then write the output to `output_file`.  Be careful though, if `output_file` already exists, it will be completely overwritten without any warning.

Comment: `<`, `>`, and `|` are all good tools to know.  `script1 | script2` will take the output of `script1` and feed it into `script2` as input.

Comment: `>>` is another useful tool.  `myscript >> output_file` will append the output from `myscript` to the end of `output_file`.

Comment: thanks for the response. see Updates above. It's actually a java process being kicked off by a shell script. no luck with these suggestions so far.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the `expect` program that is available as package for most linux distributions. It uses a simple script language to feed interactive programs. An example script can be like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn passwordmanager
expect "Enter password for testuser:"
send "verysecret123"
```

This script would tell `expect` to launch the program `passwordmanager`, then wait for the prompt `Enter password for testuser:` and answer it with `verysecret123` and so on.

Answer (score -1):

How about a shell function

```
function script_plus ()
{
   if [ $# != 2 ]; then echo "usage: ..."; exit; fi
   src=$1;
   tgt=$2;
   if [ ! -f $src ]; then echo "usage: ..."; exit; fi
   cat $src | xargs script > $tgt
}
```

Assumes 'script' is your vendor script.  Does no error checking (for illustration only).  If not a shell function, the body of the above `script_plus` could be the content of a shell script file.

Comment: You have some code problems -- for example, you have `src` where you need `"$src"` -- but more fundamentally, I don't think that `script_plus FOO BAR` is at all superior to `script < FOO > BAR`, and I don't think this is an approach worth recommending.

Comment: Thanks, fixed with xargs.  Of course 'worth recommending' changes when one needs to augment the script with error/arg checking.  Input exists , for example.

Comment: `xargs` is definitely not what the OP needs. The existing script doesn't take these things as command-line parameters; rather, it "walks through a series of user inputs".